# Can we create multiple containers in Google Tag Manager under one domain?

Tags: google-tag-manager

My requirement here is to create multiple containers under the same domain and the same account.

example: www.gtmexample.com

if possible, Do containers have different Container IDs and can i give the container names like: DNS, SDN, PRD.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple container on page with different ID. For example following are different containers under same domain.

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>

<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-YYYY');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

For more reference you can review at https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#multiple-containers